# How to use $unset when the key being removed contains a dot in its name?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

How to use `$unset` when a key contains dots in its name?

```js
const key = "test"
const result = await db.collection(collection).updateOne(
    { [key]: { $exists: true } },
    { $unset: { [pathToKey]: 1 } }
);
```

given this document:

```js
{
  "test": {
    "a": "b",         // <- test.a successfully erases the 'a' key
    "v0.0.1": "ok"    // <- test.v0.0.1 fails
  }
}
```

when `pathToKey` is `'test.a'` it successfully erases the `a` key

when it `'test.v0.0.1'` it fails, probably because the key contains a `.` in its name

I'm using the latest Mongo version

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Chiy7DtIqWb

I also tried using `$unsetField`: https://mongoplayground.net/p/MNyfhh1vdDW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$setField` with `$$REMOVE`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$test",
              {}
            ]
          },
          {}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "test": {
        "$setField": {
          "field": "v0.0.1",
          "input": "$test",
          "value": "$$REMOVE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2SxZKse0BcO)

---

For a nested object, chain up the above solution with `$mergeObjects`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "test": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$test",
          {
            "b": {
              "$setField": {
                "field": "b",
                "input": "$test.b",
                "value": "$$REMOVE"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7wdxnTI0Tce)

Comment: Could you please use an example with a nested object as on my last playground?

Comment: and on this case? https://mongoplayground.net/p/DtTaDi37yYe

Comment: @Jabu You need to chain up with `$arrayToObject` like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TSUyL7JdK2v). At this point, I doubt that a realistic  real-life schema would be complex like this. If this is a real use case, you need to refactor your schema instead of making the aggregation more complex to introduce more tech debts.

Comment: This is so complex, and when it's two+ levels nested but without . on the paths? i mean: https://mongoplayground.net/p/xT0aFq9vK1B

Comment: @Jabu The complexity comes from your complex schema. As I mentioned before, you should review your schema to see why it is so complex and refactor to simplify it, rather than coming up with some overly complicated aggregation to transform it.

Comment: could you please point out how to solve the playground in my previous comment? its the last doubt i have

Comment: @Jabu Your last one is actually simpler since the dot only appears in the innermost object. See [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/56rWwwFs4TG)

Answer (score 0):

The keys with dots are not supported by MongoDB
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names

Maybe you could use a workaround but i think it will be better to use different keys

Comment: Its supported since mongo5.0

Comment: maybe this could be useful. The example is using the $ but maybe it could be the same with dots:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/#updates-using-aggregation-pipelines

`Use $setField, $getField, and $literal in the $replaceWith stage to modify dollar ($) prefixed fields in an aggregation pipeline.`

Comment: Just a note, the documentation you linked reads `The server permits storage of field names that contain dots (.) and dollar signs ($).` which seems to be saying the opposite of your answer.